# How to convert number of day to timestamp in informix

Tags: oracle, informix

In oracle I have function which take number of days after 1.1.1900 (Java) and convert it to timestamp it looks like:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP( day + 2447893, 'J');
```

so for example when day = 8843 it should return  19.3.2014

what is the equivalent this function in informix ?

Comment: Hudi, this example of your oracle function is very unclear. At oracle, the `to_timestamp` receive a [char as parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions201.htm#SQLRF51903), do not make sense this example you posted... please, edit your question with a effective example (`select to_timestamp(...) from dual`) executed into a sqlplus or any other isql tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrote stored function that uses `INTERVAL` with days of precision 5:

```
... DATETIME(1990-01-01) YEAR TO DAY + INTERVAL(8843) DAY(5) TO DAY ...
```